# Tricky system recovery point scenario

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, windows-8.1, system-restore

Alright, I'll get right to it.

**How do you create an active system recovery point in windows 8.1 on 1 hard drive covering 2 hard drives in a computer?**

Basically I want my 1TB HDD continuously doing this and not my OS SSD on my laptop.  The laptop I got is asus rog g750jm-ds71 and yes I already updated everything.  I would really be grateful if someone could give me some advice on this.  I googled it and couldn't find anything on my particular scenario.

Comment: You want to have system restore points on a **different** drive to where they are now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source [How to Change the System Restore location](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/how-to-change-the-system-restore-location/5a3ea4fe-953a-4302-9821-638ad71535a9)

> The System Restore points are stored in the System Volume Information
> folder. This is a hidden folder. Follow these steps to display the
> folder.
>
> - In File Explorer, select the View Tab.
> - On the right side, click the Options drop down menu and select Change
>   folder and search options.
> - In the Folder Options dialog, click the View Tab.
> - Select the option Show hidden files, folders and drives.
> - Click Apply OK.
>
> **You cannot move this folder off of the drive that System Restore is
> monitoring.**

...

> **Does this mean that if W8 is on Partition "C" that the System Recovery Points MUST BE stored on Partition "C" as well and can NOT be stored on another partition (as I would like them to be)?**
>
> Yes. Restore points are 100% tied to the partition they are made on
> and cannot be moved. Ever. They are of no use to any other drive, even
> for storage as restore points work on a much deeper level on the
> system that folder redirection cannot cover.
>
> Your best bet is to use the System Restore options to control how much
> space System Restore points will take on the drive, then configure
> your external hard drive for something like File History or Windows 7
> File Recovery (the old backup tool).

Comment: Thx you so much, I'm so glad I didn't pay microsoft 100$.  I called them yesterday and was very specific on what I wanted to do.  They said they could do it for me but they would need to charge me.  I thought this would be a simple task or trick that I was missing that they could have just told me.